# How to create a new empty file / template file in Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop?

Tags: files, templates

Recently, I freshly installed the Ubuntu 16.10 on my desktop and when I right click the desktop or inside a folder, I cannot find out an option for creating an empty file / my template files. There is only an option for creating new folder. What can I do?

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/16.10/ubuntu-help/files-templates.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can go into your `~/Templates` folder and create templates yourself, then they will appear in the right-click menu. For instance:

```
touch ~/Templates/Untitled.txt
```

Comment: It works! But I am wondering why Ubuntu does not provide us some pre-created files.

Comment: @CasperLI: They used to have an in-built option for an empty text file, but for some reason upstream GNOME developers decided to remove it.

Comment: [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/uqLjWqi.png): What am I missing on my Ubuntu 16.10 installation?

Comment: This did not work for me after upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10

Comment: If you are using a system language other than English (e.g. Chinese), the folder may be named in your local language (e.g. `~/模板/` in Chinese), and writing into `~/Templates` does nothing.

Answer (score 6):

If you need some templates you can get some from this download (found it on [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=241677):

```
wget http://stalefries.googlepages.com/Templatesv4.zip
```

Contents:

```
 $ tree
.
├── Fontforge Font.sfd
├── HyperText Markup Language.html
├── Images
│   ├── Scalable Vector Graphic.svg
│   └── Xara Xtreme Graphic.xar
├── Office
│   ├── Abiword Document.awt
│   ├── Microsoft Office
│   │   ├── Excel Spreadsheet.xlt
│   │   ├── Powerpoint Presentation.pot
│   │   └── Word Document.doc
│   └── OpenDocument
│       ├── OpenDocument Database.odb
│       ├── OpenDocument Document.ott
│       ├── OpenDocument Drawing.otg
│       ├── OpenDocument Formula.odf
│       ├── OpenDocument Presentation.otp
│       ├── OpenDocument Spreadsheet.ots
│       └── Templates
│           ├── Presentations
│           │   ├── Chalkboard.otp
│           │   ├── Compladients.otp
│           │   ├── OOo Professional.otp
│           │   └── Squares.otp
│           └── Trifold brochure.ott
├── Rich Text Format.rtf
├── Scripts
│   ├── Perl Script.pl
│   ├── Python Script.py
│   └── Shell Script.sh
└── Text File.txt
```

Image:

[image]

edit: for the directories to show up I needed to do a `nautilus -q` and open nautilus.

From [Apache OpenOffice Templates](http://templates.openoffice.org/nl/template/sample-ubuntu-template-1). Several listed but  picktemplates_111.otp is related to Ubuntu.

- Opens an apache openoffice template with an Ubuntu background:

  [image]

... and another set from [apache openoffice](http://templates.openoffice.org/nl/template/sample-ubuntu-template-0).

Answer (score 0):

1. Using >file_name.file_extention

   ```
   >file_name.file_extention

   For ex. - >test.txt
   ```
2. Using touch filename.fileextention

   ```
   touch file_name.file_extention

   For ex. - touch test.txt
   ```
3. create any fileextention template in Home/Templates and you can
   access that template to create file. For ex. create test.txt file in
   Home/Templates folder. Now wherever you wants to create an .txt
   extention file you can simply create using

   ```
   right click-> New Document- -> test
   ```