# How can I use Templates in Nautilus file manager of Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: nautilus, 16.10, templates

**I followed the answers provided in:**

- [How to create a new empty file / template file in Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837227/how-to-create-a-new-empty-file-template-file-in-ubuntu-16-10-desktop)
- [Templates for commonly-used document types](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.10/ubuntu-help/files-templates.html)

**Problem:**

I still don't have the context menu entry "New Document" in Nautilus of Ubuntu 16.10.

**System:**

- Ubuntu 16.10
- Nautilus 1:3.20.3-1ubuntu3.1

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I can't comment, so providing an "answer", instead. It's answered here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus Install and use "[nautilus-actions](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions/)", as per that post.