# Create new file on ubuntu

Tags: 19.04

I've returned to ubuntu with ubuntu 19.04 and I trie to create a new file with rigth clik but the oprtion to create a new file is not shown¿it's possible to cerate a file without the terminal?

this is `journalctl -b | grep nautilus`

```
abr 29 17:23:18 user-MS-7850 dbus-daemon[1648]: [session uid=1000 pid=1648] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.128' (uid=1000 pid=6743 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
abr 29 17:23:47 user-MS-7850 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.643' (uid=1000 pid=6743 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
abr 29 17:23:47 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2423: signal 'can-accept-item' is invalid for instance '0x55cd82f7c6b0' of type 'NautilusCanvasViewContainer'
abr 29 17:27:27 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: Source ID 13589 was not found when attempting to remove it
abr 29 17:27:27 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: Source ID 13843 was not found when attempting to remove it
abr 29 17:28:06 user-MS-7850 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.643' (uid=1000 pid=6743 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
abr 29 17:28:06 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2423: signal 'can-accept-item' is invalid for instance '0x55cd82f7c910' of type 'NautilusCanvasViewContainer'
abr 29 17:28:27 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: Source ID 17799 was not found when attempting to remove it
abr 29 17:28:28 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: Source ID 18033 was not found when attempting to remove it
abr 29 17:28:29 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: Source ID 18106 was not found when attempting to remove it
abr 29 18:36:36 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Falló al ejecutar el proceso hijo «net» (No such file or directory)
abr 29 18:38:23 user-MS-7850 dbus-daemon[966]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.695' (uid=1000 pid=6743 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
abr 29 18:38:24 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2423: signal 'can-accept-item' is invalid for instance '0x55cd82f7c450' of type 'NautilusCanvasViewContainer'
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_get_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_get_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_label_set_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_get_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_get_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_label_set_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_get_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_get_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_transition_type: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_label_set_markup: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
abr 29 18:39:12 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:17 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: Source ID 102500 was not found when attempting to remove it
abr 29 18:39:17 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: Source ID 102576 was not found when attempting to remove it
abr 29 18:39:19 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:19 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:19 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:19 user-MS-7850 nautilus[6743]: gtk_revealer_set_reveal_child: assertion 'GTK_IS_REVEALER (revealer)' failed
abr 29 18:39:39 user-MS-7850 nautilus[11601]: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2423: signal 'can-accept-item' is invalid for instance '0x55a356f12180' of type 'NautilusCanvasViewContainer'
abr 29 18:39:39 user-MS-7850 nautilus[11601]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Falló al ejecutar el proceso hijo «net» (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a new empty file / template file in Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837227/how-to-create-a-new-empty-file-template-file-in-ubuntu-16-10-desktop)

Comment: @CharlesGreen I don't believe that works on 19.04.

Comment: I't doesn't work on 19.04

Comment: @Jos Do I have some special version of 19.04?  No.  The procedure still works!  I'll write up an answer

Comment: @afs125874 The "gtk-revealer" messages are indicating that between nautilus and gtk, there is a problem somewhere.  I don't have the requisite knowledge to fix that, however.

Comment: @afs125874 You *might* try `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f` - I did read that similar errors can be caused by missing components of the libgtk libraries.

Answer (score 5):

You can enable the "New Document" context menu item by creating templates in the `~/Templates` folder.  These templates should be empty documents, unless of course you always wish to start with some pre-entered data.

For example,

1. start `gedit`, the text editor
2. Press "Save" and save the document as 'untitled' in "/home/username/Templates"
3. Open `nautilus` the file manager
4. Right click in an emty area of the file manager, and the context menu will now allow you to create a new, empty text document.

This will also work with the various LibreOffice document types, and I suspect many others.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also works for us late adopters still on 18.04, nice

Comment: I tried but is not working

Comment: @afs125874 Are you running Wayland or Xorg as window manager?  NVM - it works for me on both.

Comment: @afs125874 Can you check your journal to see if there are errors related to nautilus?  Something like `journalctl -b | grep nautilus`

Comment: I've added `journalctl -b | grep nautilus` output to the original post

Comment: If you don't have Template folder:
mkdir -p ~/Templates && touch ~/Templates/Untitled\ Document; 
xdg-user-dirs-update --set TEMPLATES ~/Templates; 
nautilus -q && nautilus &