# Ubuntu 20.04 desktop - create new document

Tags: files, 20.04, menu

Any-1 know is there possible way to add "create new" context menu in desktop of Ubuntu 20.04? I see it's working in "Files" (in folders) using templates, but my only option right now is to open desktop folder in "Files" and then right-click to choose "create new".
Is the context menu on desktop customizable in any way?
Also moving files by drag/drop from desktop to "Files" doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new empty file / template file in Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837227/how-to-create-a-new-empty-file-template-file-in-ubuntu-16-10-desktop)

Comment: @karel This is not working right now in 20.04, because DesktopIcons Gnome shell extension currently does not support Templates. See my answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic desktop actions are not available on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231413/basic-desktop-actions-are-not-available-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: @VadimKotov I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the accepted answer to the linked duplicate question works perfectly in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @karel It does not work for me though. It works for me only in Nautilus, not on the desktop. There is just no menu item to create new file.

Comment: Put a shortcut to the Desktop in the Nautilus sidebar (this shortcut already exists in the Nautilus sidebar by default) and it will work on the desktop too.

Comment: @karel That's a possible workaround, thanks. But this question is about the old usual way of doing it. I've encountered this also after upgrading from 18.04.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110342/discussion-between-karel-and-vadim-kotov).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the desktop is [now handled not by Nautilus, but by DesktopIcons Gnome shell extension](https://csorianognome.wordpress.com/2017/12/21/nautilus-desktop-plans/).

And it just does not have a such simple feature, that's a pity. It is already implemented, but not released yet, see [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons/-/issues/158).